# How to program a face morpher application?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I would like to write a sort of image editor in which you could put pictures of people and morph them, like with "pinch" and "punch" effects, and add things like hair or change the color of their skin. Thing is I don't know where to begin... is there a framework for image manipulation that focuses on these tasks I'm looking for? Or should I pick up some book with image manipulation algorithms and write some .Net routines? Thanks for your input!.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cody I will check those frameworks out.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know how where to begin, you should begin in a book store. Buy a book or two about computer graphics and geometry theory. It can take a long time until you program it yourself and not just "say me what to write there, I don't need to understand what I'm writing".

Some links:

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/courses/2004/Intro.Fall.04/handouts/03-morph.pdf
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/composite/composite.pdf
http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/asgn/proj5/

I think those pages describe quite well how to do it. Look there if you want to learn it and write your own implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I studied this in my native language which is not English. This is topic on several universities, so you can probably ask some students or read a list of books recommended for some courses. I added some links to my answer.